# How to Implement Custom Taxonomy Conditional Page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I want to create custom taxonomy conditional page. My post type is "laptops".

My current code dose not working. But this code work for post_type "post" section.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'mobile_laptop_category_page_template', 99 );
function mobile_laptop_category_page_template( $template ) {
    if ( wp_is_mobile() && is_taxonomy() && 'laptops' == get_post_type()) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( '/mobile/category/taxonomy-routers.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Comment: What is a “custom taxonomy conditional page”?

Comment: `is_taxonomy` is deprecated and it's not a conditional tag. Try using `is_tax()`. Refer to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax.

Comment: Thank You Filipecsweb.

Answer (score 0):

For custom taxonomy template you can create a php file in your child theme with name "taxonomy-[taxname].php for example taxonomy-laptops.php. This template will be use for any post type that contains taxonomy laptops. In taxonomy-laptops.php you could use a condtional like if post type is laptops then do something else something else.

I hope this could help you, i m a little confused with the querstion.

Comment: Your answer right for desktop version. But i want to create different taxonomy archive page. This taxonomy archive page only for mobile version.